# Linear transformation composition with polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, transformation

I tried searching the web about this and came up with [one question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1699580/composition-of-linear-transformations-in-a-polynomial-form) on StackExchange that no one answered.

So my question is, If I have a linear transformation $T:R_3[x]\rightarrow R_3[x]$ where T is defined like so:
$$T(p(x)) = p(x+1) - xp'(x)$$
Where p'(x) is the polynomial derivative, what do I assign if I put any polynomial in $T$ in the right side?

I mean, if I need to solve for $T(1)$ or $T(x)$, where do I assign 1 or x in the transformation?

I thought that I just replace the $x$ in the $p$, (for example: $T(1) = p(1+1)-xp'(1)=2$, which is wrong... (By the way, I dont know why I need to leave the $x$ outside the $p$ alone)

What really confused me is that (and this is the answer from the exam I took):
$$T(1) = 1$$
$$T(x) = (x+1) - x(1) = 1$$
$$T(x^2) = (x+1)^2 - x(2x) = -x^2+2x+1$$

How did they get to $T(1) = 1$? What did they assign to the transformation?

How did they get to $T(x) = 1$? How come here $(x+1)$ is left alone?

How did they get to $T(x^2) = -x^2+2x+1$? How come $(x+1)$ is squared?

I searched all over the internet with different text but didn't come to anything close to answering my question..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For example $T(x^7)=(x+1)^7-x.(7x^6)$.

Comment: @AbdallahHammam Why did you put power of 7 there ($(x+1)^7$)? that's the part im not getting.. and why T(1) make that part 1?

Comment: it is just an example as i said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$T(1)$ means that you take $p(x)=1$ So $$T(1)=1+0=1$$ and so on...

Comment: Why did you removed the $x$ from $(x+1)$? why does $p(x) = x$ leave $(x+1)$ as is? why the 1 there stays and not only the $x$?

Comment: if $p(x)=1$ then $p(x+1)=1$

Comment: Sorry I don't understand, if $p(x)=1$, how did you arrive from this to $p(x+1) = 1$? what did you replace from $p(x+1)$ to get to 1?

Comment: if $p(x)=x$, then $p(x+1)=x+1$ and $xp^\prime(x)=x$ hence the result is just 1.

Comment: $p(x)=1$ means that $p$ is constant, so it is $1$ for all $x's$

Comment: The $xp'(x)$ I get, but what does it mean $p(x+1)$? If I get only one parameter to the transformation $T(p(1))$, what does $p(x+1)$ mean? EDIT: Ok so if all $x=1$ I replace $p(x+1)$ with $p(1+1)$? this is the part I am not getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47899/discussion-between-mathmath-and-zik332).